# Loop Problems #2 Switch command / Breakin loop

Tags: powershell, loops, switch-statement, break

Hey guys im still trying to figure out how to use loops in the right way for my script.

The only Problem im having now is that when the switch begins and i dont pick any option (1,2 or Q) it jumps over to the second part where "loop Done" is written.

I have the same Problem when the Loop is done once and i get asked if i want to Repeat or Quit by Using R or Q.

Is there a way to avoid this? A break or else command which could make me return to the Menu if i dont use 1,2,R or Q?

```
function Show-Menu
{
    ([string]$Title = '? ')
    cls
    Write-Host "================ $Title ================"
    Write-Host "1: Wählen Sie '1' für $F1"
    Write-Host "2: Wählen Sie '2' für $F2"
    Write-Host "Q: Wählen Sie 'Q' zum Beenden."
}

$F1 = "Test1"
$F2 = "Test2"

do
{
    Show-Menu
    $input = Read-Host "Bitte wählen Sie aus."
    switch ($input)
    {
        '1' { 
            $vorname = Read-Host "Bitte Vornamen eingeben:"
            $name = Read-Host "Bitte Namen eingeben:"
            $short = Read-Host "Bitte Kürzel eingeben:"
        }

        '2' {
            $short = Read-Host "Bitte Benutzernamen eingeben:"
            $info = Read-Host -Prompt 'Bitte Beschreibung eingeben.'
        }

        'q' {
            return
        }
    }

    do
    {
        Write-Host "Loop done"
        Clear-Variable -Name vorname,short,name,info
        $response = Read-Host "Drücken Sie R zum Wieder holen, Q zum Beenden" 
        if ($response -eq "Q")
        {
            exit
        }
    } until ($response -eq "R")
} until ($input -eq 'q')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check your variables before getting the `switch`, and `continue` if none of the expected values are found.

Using the `default` block in a switch would the more elegant way of dealing with this but found `continue`/`break` there apply to the most internal block (as expected) instead of the outer `do` block.

```
function Show-Menu
{
  (
           [string]$Title = '? '
     )
     cls
     Write-Host "================ $Title ================"
     Write-Host "1: Wählen Sie '1' für $F1"
     Write-Host "2: Wählen Sie '2' für $F2"
     Write-Host "Q: Wählen Sie 'Q' zum Beenden."
}

$F1 = "Test1"
$F2 = "Test2"

do
{
    Show-Menu
    $input = Read-Host "Bitte wählen Sie aus."

    if($input -notin @(1,2,"q")){
        Continue
    }

    switch ($input)
    {
        '1' {
                $vorname = Read-Host "Bitte Vornamen eingeben:"
                $name = Read-Host "Bitte Namen eingeben:"
                $short = Read-Host "Bitte Kürzel eingeben:"
            }
        '2' {
                $short = Read-Host "Bitte Benutzernamen eingeben:"
                $info = Read-Host -Prompt 'Bitte Beschreibung eingeben.'
            }
        'q' {
                return
            }
         default {
            # this will be executed if $input does not match another option.
            # continue/break will apply to the switch block, not the do block
         }
    }

    do
    {
        Write-Host "Loop done"
        Clear-Variable -Name vorname,short,name,info
        $response = Read-Host "Drücken Sie R zum Wieder holen, Q zum Beenden" 

        if($response -notin @("r","q")){
            Continue
        }        

        if ($response -eq "Q")
        {
            exit
        }
    }until ($response -eq "R")

}until ($input -eq 'q')
```

Comment: This fixed the first Problem, thanks for that already.
The problem that is still there is that i would like to jump from the "do" back to the "switch" part ( when i hit R for repeat). How do i manage that?

Comment: My mistake. Thats correct. But not when i hit a random Key. R  Repeats ,Q Quits. Random Letter Repeats only the "do" part, it doesnt go back to the Menu.

Comment: So to confirm you want pressing a random key to have the same behavior as hitting R? In that case that second `do` loop can be removed and the code much simplified.